# DDD how to name different event handlers for same event

Tags: domain-driven-design, naming-conventions, naming, clean-architecture

I have a website where sellers post products for sale and buyers offer to buy the product. When the seller accepts the offer an event OfferAcceptedEvent is raised. I have two side effects: 1. the buyer aggregate has to be notified that his offer has been accepted because he needs to add the offer to his bought products collection 2. The product aggregate should change state to sold. How to name these two event handlers?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply name the event handlers after what they do, for instance *SetSold* and *AddToShoppingBasket* respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I use **UseCaseName**On**EventName** pattern for naming event handlers. In your case, it would be:

1. `NotifyBuyerOnOfferAcceptedEvent`
2. `ChangeProductStateOnOfferAcceptedEvent`